# How do I change the default for the "df" command in Unix/Linux?

Tags: linux, unix

I am in the Unix/Linux Terminal under a specific directory that is owned by another person. In the terminal, I'm trying to change a default for the "df" command. When I type in the "df" command, I see the amount of disk free space listed in KILOBYTES. I want to change the default so that when I type in "df" alone, I will see the disk free space in MEGABYTES. I already know that when I type "df -m" or "df -h" I will see it in MEGABYTES, but I strictly just want to type in "df" so that I can see the values in MEGABYTES. If I can get a step by step on how to make this possible on changing the default for the "df" command to MEGABYTES any any screenshots as to what I can do, I would love that. I was told that command line flags also could affect how this command could work, so I would also like clarification on that as well. I need literally step for step on everything on this.

Answer (score 2):

Add an alias somewhere in an initialization script:

```
alias df='df -m'
```

So you could add that in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or such if you're using `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

create an alias in your bash.rc file like:

```
alias df='df -m'
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's coreutils `df` another way is to export the desired size in `DF_BLOCK_SIZE` or `BLOCKSIZE`:

```
export DF_BLOCK_SIZE=1048576
df
```